# Method returns a value but the compiler indicates a missing return

Tags: java

I'm returning the instance of my sort classes that all inherit from the TestTimes class.

However, when I return the instance, I'm getting an error, saying I need to return a result of type TestTimes.

It also says this: "missing 'default:' on 'switch' has been suppressed," which is perhaps related to this problem?

```
public TestTimes runSort(SortType sortType, ArrayType arrayType, int arraySize, int numberOfTimes) {

    switch (sortType) {
        case BubbleSort :
            BubbleSort bs = new BubbleSort();
            switch (arrayType) {
            case Increasing :
                for(int i = 0; i < numberOfTimes; i++)
                    bs.sort(createArray(arrayType, arraySize));
                break;
            case Random : 
                for(int i = 0; i < numberOfTimes; i++)
                    bs.sort(createArray(arrayType,arraySize));
                break;

            }
            return bs;

        case InsertionSort: 
            InsertionSort is = new InsertionSort();
            switch (arrayType) {
            case Increasing:
                for(int i = 0; i < numberOfTimes; i++)
                is.sort(createArray(arrayType, arraySize));
                break;
            case Random:
                for(int i = 0; i < numberOfTimes; i++)
                    is.sort(createArray(arrayType, arraySize));
                break;


            }
        return is;
    }
}
```

Comment: So what do you return if `sortType` is neither of those two? Even if `SortType` is an `enum` of only those two, the `enum` can change, so there's no future guarantee, and so compiler ask what to do when that happens.

Comment: Even though you know that case coverage is exhaustive, Java compiler has no idea. It assumes that you could possibly pass something other than `BubbleSort` and `InsertionSort` for `sortType`, and something other than `Increasing` and `Random` for `arrayType`. That's why Java asks for a `return` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

All of the "logical" paths through a method need to return based on the method's contract. In your case, you have a switch statement, but only defined two explicit cases and no default. This is like having an `if`-`else if` without an `else` -- what if you don't meet either condition?

Simplified, you have something like this:

```
public SomeType doSomething(SomeEnum enumValue) {
    switch(enumValue) {
        case SomeEnum.FOO:
            // do something
            return something;
        case SomeEnum.BAR:
            // ...
            return something;
    }

    // But what if enumValue is neither? We end up here ... with no return!
}
```

What if your enum isn't either of those values?

This is what your compiler is trying to tell you. Now, if these are the only supported values, you might want to throw an exception like an `IllegalArgumentException` to indicate a bad input. Or perhaps you want to return a null or a different indicator.

This is why it's not good to suppress the compiler warning related to the switch missing the default case -- because it often indicates, as you have here, that you have a missing path in your logic. Also, what if you at some point add a new type of search to your enum? Even though you only support Bubble and Insertion sort now, maybe you'll want to support a Radix sort later, but there will be no handling in the method for that yet.

You should add a `default` case to your switch, or add an explicit `return` or `throws` at the bottom of your method to handle the fall-through cases that you don't explicitly support

For example, with `default`:

```
switch(sortType) {
    case BubbleSort:
        return ...;
    case InsertionSort:
        return ...;
    default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Only BubbleSort and InsertionSort supported!");
}
```

Or, alternatively, with an explicit return:

```
public TestTimes runSort (...) {
    switch(sortType) {
      case BubbleSort:
          return ...;
      case InsertionSort:
          return ...;
    }
    // we'll end up here with any other sort type...
    return null; // or throw new Exception(...) etc
}
```